# What is a good way to erase the entire data and load the new data in a service table?

Tags: mysql, database

I am new in MySQL.

I receive full metadata every day.

However, I do not know which data is added, deleted and updated.

I use MySQL and the size of the data is about one million.

What is a good way to erase the entire data and load the new data in a service table?

I think about the following methods.

first option,

Run Delete and insert in a transaction.

second option,

RENAME TABLE foo TO foo_old, foo_new To foo

Please advise me how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can truncate the table and import your new data afterwards. You dont need to rename anything.

```
query truncate:
TRUNCATE TABLE {tableName};

cli import:
mysql -u {username} -p {database} < {importFile.sql}
```

Comment: I think you are missing TABLE keyword after TRUNCATE, and also the {database} field should be {password}.

Comment: Nope you are wrong with both.TABLE is optional but you are right more "clean" and -p gives a password prompt after hitting return. With password it would be -p{password} {database}. The password without whitespace after -p flag.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Ben is perfect if you have data outside MySQL in a file. If your data is in another table then try this:

```
    # Truncate table 
      truncate table table_name;

    # Inserting data to new table, Provided, same column names in succession
      insert into target_table_name select * from old_table_name;

    (or)

      insert into target_table_name (column names) select column_names from old_table_name;
```